# gccgo, AIX: compiled .o files does not contain .go_export section

Tags: go, gcc, aix, powerpc, gccgo

I am trying to build gccgo (9.2) on AIX and facing now a problem I can't solve.

The machine: AIX 7.1, Processor Type: PowerPC_POWER7, CPU Type: 64-bit, Kernel Type: 64-bit

The Error: "./sync/atomic.gox exists but does not contain any Go export data".

So I looked at atomic.gox and it is empty. (All .gox files are empty). 
So next I looked how atomic.gox is created. The file is created by `objcopy -j .go_export sync/.libs/atomic.o`. So the .go_export section of atomic.o is used to create atomic.gox. With `objdump -s atomic.o` I figured out, that atomic.o does not have any .go_export section, just ".text, .data and .debug". So the wrong behavior is located at the creation of the .o file. For the creation of the atomic.o file i found the following line:

> libtool: compile:  /OS/COMPSRV/trunk/user1/src/gccgo-obj/./gcc/gccgo
>   -B/OS/COMPSRV/trunk/user1/src/gccgo-obj/./gcc/ -B/opt/freeware/gcc9/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.5.0/bin/ -B/opt/freeware/gcc9/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.5.0/lib/ -isystem /opt/freeware/gcc9/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.5.0/include -isystem
>   /opt/freeware/gcc9/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.5.0/sys-include -O2 -g -I . -c
>   -fgo-pkgpath=sync/atomic ../.././../gccgo-src/libgo/go/sync/atomic/doc.go
>   ../.././../gccgo-src/libgo/go/sync/atomic/value.go  -fPIC -o
>   sync/.libs/atomic.o

These are my configure parameter:

> languages="--enable-languages=go,c,c++"
>
> options="CC=/opt/freeware/bin/gcc --without-gnu-ar --without-gnu-as
>   --with-gnu-ld --with-gmp-include=/usr/include/gmp --disable-bootstrap --with-gmp-lib=/usr/lib --with-mpfr-include=/usr/include/mpfr --with-mpfr-lib=/usr/lib --with-mpfr=/usr/include --with-mpc=/usr/include --disable-nls --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-lto --disable-libgomp"
>
> multilib="--enable-multilib"
>
> shared="--enable-shared"
>
> static="--enable-static"

Further information:
I am using gcc 8.3

**Edit:**

**Suggested solutions:**

- I added --enable-libgo, but the error is still there

Comment: Maybe this is a limitation of the AIX linker (`ld`)?

Answer (score 0):

one thing that looks suspicious is that you don't seem to be passing --enable-libgo to configure. Maybe give that a try to see if it helps?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: When I tried to comment, it told me "You must have 50 reputation to comment." Tell you what, since you can comment, why don't you post my suggestion as a comment and I'll delete the answer. Sound reasonable? [NB: apparently the "must have 50" rule doesn't apply to comments on my own posts.] https://pasteboard.co/IZHPLSFo.png